# Where in Stack Exchange can I ask interview-related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

There are lots of Q&A site on Stack Exchange.

I asked a question on Programmers. But it was migrated to Stack Overflow.

There are many questions about data structures and algorithms asked on Stack Overflow, but some are downvoted, and I don't know why.

Is there a specific Stack Exchange site to post algorithm (data structure) questions? Or, more precisely, do we have stack exchange site for people who face interviews?

Which Stack Exchange site is meant for what?

Comment: You have read the FAQ I assume? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Could you clarify what sort of question you mean exactly? "People who face interview" could have lots of questions, including what type of tie to wear, how to match their socks, or what type of deodorant has the most impact on interviewers.

Comment: (Not too sure about my edit on the title. Please re-edit if I missed your point.)

Comment: data structures, algorithm, technical details alone

Comment: Interview questions always fare poorly at SE sites.  Not in the least because they are asked a week or less before the interview.  Way too late, programmers need to prepare for one about 4 years ahead of it.  Nothing useful you can do in a week, other than studying the company you interview with to see if you might like working for them.  That's too localized.

Comment: @Mat The deodorant question alone makes me want to start a A51 proposal for interview questions :D

Comment: i already proposed data structure in it. but how it works? i mean does it need followers or what to become beta then to be in action?

Comment: @Dineshkumar: how about [reading the FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)? Also it appears you forgot to search before entering that proposal. There's already an Interview proposal.

Answer (score 2):

[algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) and [data-structures](/questions/tagged/data-structures) questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow.  If some of them are closed, it's because they're unclear, incomplete, etc.

Comment: well some of them are straightforward and clear but still closed or downvoted.

Comment: @Dineshkumar If you think they shouldn't be closed, you can edit them to improve the question and vote to reopen.  I can't do much if you don't specify which ones you're talking about.